# Can i get the messages from Gmail IMAP?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, gmail-imap

I want read all messages with gmail account using Java and IMAP.
Can i do this, or now i need to use OAuth and Gmail API?
That is my Java simple code:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;

public class ReadingEmail {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        try {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
            session.setDebug(true);
            Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
            store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "email", "pass");
            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            Message msg = inbox.getMessage(inbox.getMessageCount());
            Address[] in = msg.getFrom();
            for (Address address : in) {
                System.out.println("FROM:" + address.toString());
            }
            Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
            BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(0);
            System.out.println("SENT DATE:" + msg.getSentDate());
            System.out.println("SUBJECT:" + msg.getSubject());
            System.out.println("CONTENT:" + bp.getContent());
        } catch (Exception mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But i have a error:

> My client isn't accepting my username and password

IMAP is enabled in Gmail account settings. What to do?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using C# or Java? Is your error with Java?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, that's the whole point of IMAP. You need to authenticate, though, either with [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/gmail/oauth_overview), or app-specific password (your account password will not work).